# IF statement issue background change

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I need help!

Let's say that I have an element in my page that changes background-color when scrolled.
I wanted to change the color of the a tag inside of it whei it changes the background, I tried to write a thing like this below, but it did't work! 
How can I tell jquery to act when the background changes?

```
$(function () {
    var background = $("backtotop").css('background', 'black');
    if (background = true) {
        $('a').css('color', 'white')
    }
    if (background = false) {
        $('a').css('color', 'green')
    }
});
```

Comment: the getter version is `var background=$("backtotop").css('background') == 'black'`

Comment: Best approach is to add class on scroll and in CSS you can give background as well as color to it.

Comment: and the value returned will differ based on browser.. so use class instead

Comment: What is `$("backtotop")`, I think your selector is wrong, furthermore the `.css()`-function will return a jQuery-Object and no boolean value and `=` is an assignment and no comparison as `==` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are getting string from the below line

```
var background=$("backtotop").css('background','black');
```

then do this

```
if (background == "true") {
    $('a').css('color', 'white')
}
if (background == "false") {
    $('a').css('color', 'green')
}
```

if you are getting boolean value then write as below

```
if (background) {
    $('a').css('color', 'white')
} else {
    $('a').css('color', 'green')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several syntax issues:

`$("backtotop")` is no valid selector, this would select the html-tag `backtotop` and I don't know such a tag. Rather use a ID-selector (`#`) or a class-selector (`.`).

`background` would be a jQuery-Object here and no boolean value.

`if (background = true) {`, here you are setting the value `true` to `background`. So this statement is always true, you have to use the comparison-operater `==` instead.

```
$(function () {
    var background = $("#backtotop").css('background-color', 'black'); 
    var backgroundcolor = background.css('background-color');

    if (backgroundcolor == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
        $('a').css('color', 'white')
    } else {
        $('a').css('color', 'green')
    }
});
```

Note: The getter `.css()`-function will return the rgb-value of the set background color.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q6emh7p1/)

A second approach for using classes:

```
$(function () {
    var background = $("#backtotop").addClass('black')

    if (background.hasClass('black')) {
        $('a').css('color', 'white')
    } else {
        $('a').css('color', 'green')
    }
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0dytps34/)

**Reference**

[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

[.hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

Comment: Of course the fact that I omit the # was a typing mistake, which I didn't notice and with the copy and paste spread almost everywhere! But thanks, I didn't know that the getter returned the rgb value! Interesting! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(function(){var background=$("backtotop").css('background','black')
if(background == true){$('a').css('color','white')}
if(background == false){$('a').css('color','green')}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answers guys.
I think the easiest way is to use .addClass and .removeClass, because none of the suggested methods trying to fix my piece of code worked out.

It's a shame, however, because I think that the idea of make it act as the background changes is very cool.
I think the problem is that the variable doesn't interact with the if statements.

When on the code

```
$(function () {
    var background = $("backtotop").css('background', 'black');
    if (background = true) {
        $('a').css('color', 'white')
    }
    if (background = false) {
        $('a').css('color', 'green')
    }
});
```

I use single = the color of the a tag stays permanently white,
If I use double == the color stays green.